# How to change a SKSpriteNode saturation? - Swift

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I develop a game and I'd like to have the background change its saturation over a certain amount of time, but have no idea how to do it... So here's my code:

```
        var bg = SKSpriteNode()
        bg.size = frame.size
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        bg.zPosition = -1000
        bg.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background")
        bg.alpha = 0.5

       addChild(bg)
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add you background as a child node of a `SKEffectNode` then set create a color controls filter as the effect node filter. Setting the `kCIInputSaturationKey` to values less than one will cause the background image to be desaturated, greater than one will cause the background to become more saturated.

```
var effectNode = SKEffectNode()
effectNode.addChild(bg)
effectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
effectNode.filter?.setValue(0.1, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
```